# How to open .MD file in gitbash?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, git-bash, readme

VS Code has a good preview mode for .md files. To open a file with this mode, I have to right-click the file in VS Code document tree, and click "Open Preview".
I have made a read me file using touch command, but now how to edit or open it there?

Comment: So you want to open it on terminal. use the regular command `nano <filename>` to view and edit it. use `cat <filename>` to only view it. But I don't think there's a option to preview like that vs code extension in the terminal.

Comment: I think in VSCode the idea is that you have one tab where it's open in the plain editor, and a separate tab for the Preview. It's not a wysiwyg editor, just a preview, so you have to edit it as plain text yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open `.MD file` from Vscode click on it to open, or you can open it from terminal by using this command:

> `code README.md`

If you want to open `.md` in terminal you can using `vim or nano`,`vim` work in Linux, Mac and Windows but `nano` work in linux

> `vim REAADME.md`

OR

> `nano README.md`

You can open preview mode by using this shortcut open the file and press from keyboard:

> `Shift + Ctrl + v`